# Why did phenomenalism fall out of favour in analytic philosophy?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, logical-positivism, reductionism

Modern analytic philosophy proposes various reductionist projects to reduce phenomenal terms (like redness e.t.c) into physical terms (like neural-states, functional states e.t.c) such as for example, behaviourism, functionalism or brain-mind identity theory. But why did the logical positivist project of doing an opposite kind of reduction i.e reducing physical terms into phenomenal terms go out of fashion?

Comment: Two main reasons. First, while observational reductions in 19th century were promoted by some scientists themselves (Mach and Ostwald famously), they were discredited by opposition to atomism and abandoned in 20th  century. Analytic philosophers are deferential to scientists on such matters. Second, the idea of reducing theoretical to observational/phenomenal in logical positivism presupposed some sort of "purely observational" language and [analytic/synthetic distinction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic/), which were discredited by Quine's critique.

Comment: Aren't qualia as a concept, a return of phenomenalism? "There is something it is like for me to undergo each state, some phenomenology that it has. Philosophers often use the term ‘qualia’" https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia/

Answer (score 1):

> But why did the logical positivist project of doing an opposite kind of reduction i.e reducing physical terms into phenomenal terms go out of fashion?

It sounds as if you are asking after the relationship between [theory and observation (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/science-theory-observation/#Theoryandvalueladenness) according to the logical positivists:

> Philosophers of science have traditionally recognized a special role for observations in the epistemology of science. Observations are the conduit through which the ‘tribunal of experience’ delivers its verdicts on scientific hypotheses and theories. The evidential value of an observation has been assumed to depend on how sensitive it is to whatever it is used to study. But this in turn depends on the adequacy of any theoretical claims its sensitivity may depend on.

Thus, there are phenomenological truths of observation, and they purportedly map onto physical terms to create an equivalence between phenomenological claims and physical ones. Were they trying to reduce the obective to the phenomenological? I wouldn't say that. As I understand it, logical positivistm and then the attenuated logical empiricism was a project to show that observation could be shown to be objective and equivalent to the physical thus endorsing physicalism by eliminating (or rather minimizing) the observer in true [positivist fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positivism). The spirit of positivism has always been a realist project to show that the approach to dealing with the difference between appearance and reality is to factor the observer out. One attempt to show the equivalence was the use of [Ramsey sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_sentence) to eliminate non-observable phenomena in terms of observation sentences about physical items.

Thus, the goal of Carnap and others was to strip the speculative metaphysics out of science, and reduce metaphysics to a linguistic activity, showing that what was true of observations was an objective core of ideas that aligned neatly with the inventory of physical objects of study. This is the same sort of thinking that permeates logical atomism which is the presumption that somehow the atoms of our philosophical speech are neatly aligned with objective truths that correspond to the world and why logical atomism is aligned with the [correspondent theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theory_of_truth). With the Berlin and Vienna circles, the hope was rekindled to somehow show an equivalence between observations and objects observed such that the observations would be definitive in determining truths about objects observed.

> Why did phenomenalism fall out of favour in analytic philosophy?

It has always been a positivist goal to eliminate the observer as a means to discovering truth, to eliminate the person from reality, as it were. This is seen in Fregean notions of antipsychology and reduction to logic in mathematics, and in science the project was to reduce phenomenology to the psychological in a manner of speaking by focusing on language production. This led to the idea of a linguistic analysis to ensure that observation sentences were in some sense primary to experience and free of the various theories they purported to confirm to avoid a circularity:

> One important transformation, characteristic of the linguistic turn in philosophy, was to concentrate on the logic of observation reports rather than on objects or phenomena observed. This focus made sense on the assumption that a scientific theory is a system of sentences or sentence-like structures (propositions, statements, claims, and so on) to be tested by comparison to observational evidence. It was assumed that the comparisons must be understood in terms of inferential relations. If inferential relations hold only between sentence-like structures, it follows that theories must be tested, not against observations or things observed, but against sentences, propositions, etc. used to report observations (Hempel 1935, 50–51; Schlick 1935).

Famously, Hempel and others put forth the [Deductive-Nomological model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive-nomological_model) in a bid to rigorize explanation in terms of observation, and to show that scientific theories followed deductively from observation. I like to think of it as an attempt to take observation sentences as an input, and make the explanations about physical objects deductively certain so claims of confirmation and then later verification could be wielded as objective matters of fact in the spirit of the [Leibniz's characteristica universalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristica_universalis). Carnap and compatriots were certain in the 30's it was just a matter of eliminating metaphysical frippery by linguistic analysis by devising a method to sort argumentation about [angels dancing on pinheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_many_angels_can_dance_on_the_head_of_a_pin%3F) from discourse.

From the 30's to the early 60's, what followed was a series of set backs to the programme of objectification with the project itself being acknowledged as a dismal failure by Hempel and others, particularly in light of arguments put forth by Russel Hanson (who advocated the notion of theory-ladenness), Kuhn (who put forth a sociological angle on method), and Feyerabend (who famously argues there's no method). In retrospect, the ideas of Duhem, who the Vienna and Berlin circles rail against unknowingly as far as I know, are seen to have triumphed. Quine had influentially attacked the synthetic-analytic divide, and the logical positivists and logical empiricists eventually conceded that the notion of creating an objective language and method of observation as an isomorphism of sorts to physical phenomena and showing that observation and physical things could be certain was an empty one. The philosophy of science entered its post-modernist phase as [covered excellently by Zammitto (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXxK6e07ciUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=zammitto&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiouL3XypX9AhWukokEHbJnDAYQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=zammitto&f=false).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that as a whole, analytic philosophy as a tradition denies the phenomenological (which might be seen as a modifier imputing consciousness), with the exception of radical behaviorism and perhaps radical eliminative materialism. Most analytical philosophies tacitly assume the phenomenological in one way or another. I think it's fair to say that the analytical distinction tends to try to reduce the phenomenological to language or physical states, to minimize the role of the subject, and to remain as ahistorical and avoid explicit normativity as possible in contradistinction...

Comment: to Continental thinkers who love to put the subject smack-dab in the middle of the philosophy. The Frankfurt school is one example, phenomenologists another, and philosophical anthropology is still another. Here it is important to situate thinking in a very political, temporal context.

Answer (score 0):

Phenomenology was, when first conceived of, a reductionist programme. All our observations are sensations, we combine sensations into inferences about our world, and the logic of how this is done, is plausible to characterize and formalize. The goal was to base all our worldviews on a reduction to phenomenal data bits -- quales.

Phenomenalist schools trained internal observers to identify the fundamental quales of experience.  Each of the main schools developed a detailed fundamental quale theory, and consistent observations.  However, the schools DISAGREED with each other.  And they were unable to reach agreement cross-school.

This was a surprise to the movement, the expectation was that trained scientists could reach consensus on what we observe -- this is true in observing things like oscilloscopes, spectra, the plumage patterns of birds, etc.  Observations are subjective, but we are able to reach consensus intersubjectively. But on quales, this was not the case.

The inability to reach consensus on what phenomena reduce to, was fatal to the credibility of the movement as a science field, and to the program of phenomenal reduction in general.  Note at the time, reductionism was basically unquestioned, so a failure of reduction in a field was considered fatal to the credibility of the field.

Something very similar happened to memetics, a century later.  Just as the base unit of "quale" is very difficult to identify, the base unit of "meme" is also very difficult to identify.  The problem is similar in both cases.  Quales all seem to be nearly infinitely subdividable.  Same with memes.  At some point, this subdivision seems to get one out of the class of quale, or meme, but WHEN this happens in the subdivision process -- is far from obvious.

This problem -- "what is the minimal unit of meme", was also a fatal one for memetics.  The field basically broke up, and the journals went out of print.

However, both phenomenology, and memetics, are in a bit of a revival today.  This may be traceable to the realization that LOTS of things can't be reduced.  Species, ecosystems, ecological niches, norms, etc. -- the items studied in the sciences other than physics -- don't reduce to physics.  The SEP article on Scientific Reduction notes that from about the 1990s, philosophy of science has realized the programme of global reduction does not work in the sciences.

Phenomenology might have been the first science field to establish the nondeducibility of its field definitively.  In retrospect, the shut down of both phenomenology, and memetics, due to their non-reducibility was precipitous.

For both quales and memes, we seem to only find both in communities.  We experience memeplexes, and qualia.  How to structure a science without reduction to base elements, and in particular with its items only appearing in communities -- is still an ongoing project in philosophy of science.

Analytics requires precise definitions, in order to do logical analyses.  And if one cannot define an individual quale -- that is a problem for analytics.  Analytics is basically wedded to reductionism, and to at least a limited degree, phenomenology requires accepting a version of holism relative to quales. The problem that phenomenology had relative to reductionism, made it a poor fit to analytics.

Comment: References & supporting quotes could improve this answer